# strange behavior with stack view on iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, constraints

I tried stackView as a newly swift dev, they are really convenient for layout related issue but, I still have a strange behavior on the iPhone 6 plus screen (see picture below)

- 3 image are in a stackView
- StackView is in a cell, who is in a tableview obviously.
- StackView constraint are set to be top,left,right 0 to the cell and 80% of the cell height

here is the result :

Result on iPhone 6:

[image]

Result on iPhone 6 **plus**

[image]

#### EDIT:

1. the miss-sized view happen only on iPhone **6 plus** and not on iPhone **6S plus**
2. with a constant of +14, in my case, on the cell percentage, the issue disappear (but size are no more in my design guideline)

thanks

Comment: Could you please add one more screenshot after setting the different background colours for `stackView` and for each `imageView`? Also set the `imageView`'s `clipToBounds` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried constraining the three images to have equal heights?

Comment: OK, so what are the pink/orange elements? and how are they constrained? Also, is the stack view with the images in front of the pink bits?

Comment: on the screen, the red/pink view is only cell background color

Answer (score 0):

Set equal widths across images or set content hugging and content compression priorities for images so it knows how to size the stack. In my opinion the only way here is to make them equal width.

Otherwise you will always have some sort of constraint resolution based on hugging/compression values which even if the same will give ambiguous layout or if not the same and not ambiguous, will produce difference in sizes in certain cases. Equal width on the other hand should guarantee the width.

Comment: selecting the three image and setting equal width change nothing, i even try to selecting the first image (the most cropped image) and setting a width or changing priority to hugging and it did not change anything

Comment: @MehdiS. try wrapping UIImageViews into UIViews. UIStackView sets its own constraints on each of its subviews directly. Can be it drops your constraints or simply overrides them with higher priority ones.